# Could not found file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, 3-tier

i ma running my Asp.net solution but getting error:

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="TCSCloud.WebApp.MvcApplication " Language="C#" %>
```

everything is fine, it's been imported, went through almost every stack overflow issue regarding this but didn't fix anything. help plz

My solution contains 13 projects,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rebuilding the whole solution once. It might help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the `Inherits="TCSCloud.WebApp.MvcApplication "` matches the namesspace and class name in your `Global.asax.cs` file.

So, you should have something like this in your Global.asax.cs file:

```
namespace TCSCloud.WebApp
{
    public class MvcApplication
    {
    }
}
```

Also, you have a space there at the end of your `Inherits="TCSCloud.WebApp.MvcApplication "`

Comment: @user3368990 Can you go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Projects and Solutions` -> Change the build verbosity to `Diagnostic` and see if there are any error messages there. Please post the output by adding it to your original question.